# Changing Payment Method From In-App Purchase to Third-Party Gateway in Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase

In my Android and iOS apps I'm using in_app purchase to unlock app content. Now I want to move to a third-party payment system (Braintree) that integrates with a web version of the app, and move from one-time payment to subscription (subscription will apply to an account that can be used cross-platform, and so can be used more widely than just in the app itself). However, I still need to use the old in-app purchase code to check for those users that purchased by the legacy method (those purchases will still be valid). My concern is that we are using the Google Play/App Store in-app purchase code, but without allowing new purchases using that method. Do you think we will run into issues due to this?

Comment: Your app will be rejected if you don’t use IAP on iOS

Answer (score 0):

No it won't get any problem, you can check Netflix & Spotify are also doing same